# Hide breadcrumb in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I am using **WooCommerce Breadcrumb Plugin** and I want to hide it on specific page.I am doing it with the CSS like this :

```
.page-id-X  .woocommerce-breadcrumb{visibility:hidden;}
```

Is there any other way to hide it ? Because I don't to use that way as it make it static one.

Comment: the most easy methot is it. you can hiding with your way.

Comment: Do you know anyway with the `functions.php` ?

Comment: you can use **remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );** with if

Comment: I don't know if you have read my question correctly or not but I can't do with it coz I am using **WooCommerce Breadcrumb Plugin**.In that plugin they have already disable default WooCommerce Breadcrumb.

Answer (score 0):

Change `PAGE_ID` to the actual page ID, title or slug:

```
add_action( 'init', 'se26673973_remove_wc_breadcrumbs' );
function se26673973_remove_wc_breadcrumbs()
{
    if( ! is_page( PAGE_ID ) )
        return;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't know if you have read my question correctly or not but I can't do with it coz I am using **WooCommerce Breadcrumb Plugin**.In that plugin they have already disable default WooCommerce Breadcrumb.

Comment: Must've missed that. You could ask the plugin developer for some more flexibility, or look into the dynamic `pre_option_{$option}` filter: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_(option_name)

Answer (score 0):

Edit page.php. Make an if statement with is_page to check if your specific page is viewed. Then drop your CSS property.

---

update - code:

in page.php place the following:

```
<?php 

// Check to see if the current used page is the specific one you're talking about
// Replace ID with your page ID
if (is_page(ID)){ 
?>
<style>
.page-id-X  .woocommerce-breadcrumb{visibility:hidden;}
</style>

<?php 
} // Closing the if curly braces 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But can you explain same thing with your code.
**NOTE** I have not used any page template.

Comment: Code added. Please check